# Type conversion failure while aggregation in spring data mongo query

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, type-conversion, aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb

I am using springBootVersion '2.6.4' and mongodb for database. I have Item a model class equivalent to item collection in db, Item contains a field 'cost' of type BigDecimal. I want to perform query to sum the values of 'cost' with some match criteria. Since BigDecimal values are stored as string in db, it is not able to sum up the values, was trying to convert string values to double but did not work.

**My java code for the query:**

```
Aggregation agg = Aggregation.newAggregation(match(Criteria.where("refrenceId")
       .is("630722f47b409045ff2b98ee")),
        group().sum(ToDouble.toDouble("cost")).as("cost"));
Double result= mongoConfig.getMongoTemplate().aggregate(agg, Item.class, Item.class)
        .getMappedResults().get(0).getCost().doubleValue();
```

**But its throwing exception :**

> "Command failed with error 241 (ConversionFailure): 'Failed to
> optimize pipeline :: caused by :: Failed to parse number 'cost' in
> $convert with no onError value: Did not consume whole number.' on
> server localhost:27017. The full response is {"ok": 0.0, "errmsg":
> "Failed to optimize pipeline :: caused by :: Failed to parse number
> 'cost' in $convert with no onError value: Did not consume whole
> number.", "code": 241, "codeName": "ConversionFailure"}"

Is there anything I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Add a `$`. 
`ToDouble.toDouble("$cost")`

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not store them as a string, so that you can make these kind of queries. An appropriate format would be Decimal128.
You can register a custom conversions bean for that. (BigDecimal is what i use in my Document class, if you use something else, then you would need to convert from that to Decimal128 in this case)

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MongoCustomConversions;

@Configuration
public class MongoConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public MongoCustomConversions mongoCustomConversions() {
        return new MongoCustomConversions(Arrays.asList(new BigDecimalToDecimal128Converter(),
                new Decimal128ToBigDecimalConverter()));
    }
}
```

And the 2 converters would be:

```
public class Decimal128ToBigDecimalConverter implements Converter<Decimal128, BigDecimal> {

    @Override
    public BigDecimal convert(Decimal128 source) {
        return source.bigDecimalValue();
    }
}
public class BigDecimalToDecimal128Converter implements Converter<BigDecimal, Decimal128> {

    @Override
    public Decimal128 convert(BigDecimal source) {
        return Decimal128.parse(source.toString());
    }
}
```